# Is there any way to unmarshal JSON into a map and preserve keys order

Tags: json, go

I need to unmarshal JSON data into the map by preserving the order of keys and values.

**This is a JSON data example:**

```
{
    "31ded736-4076-4b1c-b38f-7e8d9fa78b41": {
      "Name": "Requested",
      "Items": [
        { "ID": "c7ac5b7f-59b0-45e3-82fb-b3b0afc05f55", "GroupName": "First task" , "NumQuestion": "10" ,"Score":"10"},
        {"ID": "17acf9a1-b2c7-46c6-b975-759b9d9f538d", "GroupName": "Test1" , "NumQuestion": "20" ,"Score":"5" }
      ]
    },
    "115f7d04-3075-408a-b8ce-c6e46fe6053f": {
      "Name": "To do",
      "Items": [
        { "ID": "c7ac5b7f-59b0-45e3-82fb-b3b0afc05f56", "GroupName": "First task" , "NumQuestion": "5" ,"Score":"10"}
      ]
    },
    "9bcf1415-3a41-43b6-a871-8de1939a75c4": {
      "Name": "In Progress",
      "Items": [
        { "ID": "c7ac5b7f-59b0-45e3-82fb-b3b0afc05f57", "GroupName": "Second task" , "NumQuestion": "10" ,"Score":"5"}
      ]
    },
    "2f6c1455-6cf9-4009-b86b-de0a0d2204a1": {
      "Name": "Done",
      "Items": [
        { "ID": "c7ac5b7f-59b0-45e3-82fb-b3b0afc05f58", "GroupName": "Third task" , "NumQuestion": "20" , "Score":"7"}
      ]
    }
  }
```

**This is my code:**

```
var GroupTestListUpdate = http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    type Item struct {
        ID string `json:"id"`
        GroupName string `json:"groupName"`
        NumQuestion string `json:"numQuestion"`
        Score string `json:"score"`
    }

    type Input struct {
        Name string `json:"name"`
        Items []Item `array:"item"`
    }

    var objmap map[string]Input

    reqBody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil{
        http.Error(w, "can't read body", http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
    }

    json.Unmarshal(reqBody, &objmap)
    fmt.Println(objmap)
})
```

**Output:**

```
map[115f7d04-3075-408a-b8ce-c6e46fe6053f:{To do [{c7ac5b7f-59b0-45e3-82fb-b3b0afc05f56 First task 5 10}]} 2f6c1455-6cf9-4009-b86b-de0a0d2204a1:{Done [{c7ac5b7f-59b0-45e3-82fb-b3b0afc05f58 Third task 20 7}]} 31ded736-4076-4b1c-b38f-7e8d9fa78b41:{Requested [{c7ac5b7f-59b0-45e3-82fb-b3b0afc05f55 First task 10 10} {17acf9a1-b2c7-46c6-b975-759b9d9f538d Test1 20 5}]} 9bcf1415-3a41-43b6-a871-8de1939a75c4:{In Progress [{c7ac5b7f-59b0-45e3-82fb-b3b0afc05f57 Second task 10 5}]}]
```

**Question:**

1. I want to know how to preserve the order of keys and values.
2. I got the same output every time I tried this code, So I wonder that the order in the map is not completely random?

Comment: The order is not random, it's implementation defined. So on the same computer, with the same compiler you will get the same results. There are no guarantees that you will get the same result in the future though, or on a different machine.

Comment: I don't know that the map in Golang has this issue, So I spend so much time wonder why it not in the same order, Thank you for replying to my question.

Comment: It's not an issue. The issue is that you made assumptions without actually verifying if they were correct.

Comment: Oh, So that's how it works. Thank you, Mr.super for clarifying to me.

Comment: Yes like you say It's my fault. Next time I will be more cautious, Thank you very much Mr.super.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

You can override the `UnmarshalJSON` method on a custom map type that will allow you to preserve the order.

As an example, here is a library that does just that: https://github.com/iancoleman/orderedmap.